# Auto Zoom QR code while scanning is not working

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, google-mlkit

I inspired by Gpay barcode zoom while scanning and want to do the same. I am using MlKit for QR scanning. Now I am implementing [ZoomSuggestionOptions](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/mlkit/vision/barcode/ZoomSuggestionOptions) to enable auto zoom. I implemented as per the document. But zooming is not happening.

Here is my code:

```
BarcodeScannerOptions options =
                    new BarcodeScannerOptions.Builder()
                            .setZoomSuggestionOptions(
                                    new ZoomSuggestionOptions.Builder(new ZoomSuggestionOptions.ZoomCallback() {
                                        @Override
                                        public boolean setZoom(float zoomRatio) {
                                            exchangeScannedData.setZoomValue(zoomRatio);
                                            Log.i("BarcodeScannerProcessor setZoom", "zoom called..");
                                            return true;
                                        }
                                    }).setMaxSupportedZoomRatio(5.0f).build())
                            .build();

            barcodeScanner = BarcodeScanning.getClient(options);
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: I don't know about Google Pay auto-zoom. I think it's not a camera auto-zoom but rather an image auto-zoom that is triggered when a barcode is detected. I don't have any off-the-shelf source code to post but it should be possible encoding one by applying the transform guidelines found at: https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/transform-output.